# Run script on Gnome 3 suspend

Tags: gnome, power-management

I need to run a script on Gnome's standard suspend action (via top-right taskbar menu item, with Alt key pressed)

Looks like Gnome doesn't use `pm-utils`, so I have no idea where to put my script